# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner customized for multitenant environments

Tags: junit, spring-boot, annotations, integration-testing, multi-tenant

I work on a multi tenant application. Current Tenant information is managed via thread locals, which are set via a filter for the request.
During integration tests (non-web) this filter does not apply, so I look for a method to set this thread local for unit tests.

I started thinking about an annotation on the test-class or methods (including `@Before` and `@After`). This could be something like `@AsTenant("tenantId")` (lets assume we only need the tenant id).

I basically look for a way now to extend `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` to be aware of the annotations and properly set the thread locals at the right time. Does anybody have experience or ideas on where to hook this? (I am not very familiar with test runners)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create your own `TestExecutionListener` which checks y9our test case. You can take a look at other `TestExecutionListener`s for inspiration.

Comment: This did work! Thanks!